# Want to show same pop up for notifications on a nav tab created by me in Liferay

Tags: notifications, liferay

In **Liferay** after login the **notification pop** up that is shown on clicking one of the tabs at Top Right corner of nav, want to hide that one & open that pop up on a tab button created by me. I have created a new tab but don't know how to open that on its click. Is there any predefined variable that i can provide as a value in its **href** for that or anything else?

[the pop up that is shown in the first image, i want it as it is on click of notification tab that is visible in 2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fB0p.png)

[Notification tab button at the right end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b26Hz.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to describe what problem(s) are you facing? Share the relevant code or snapshots and add further details.

Comment: i have shared two snapshots, please check if you can understand the requirement now.

Comment: All in all, you would require to change the `notifications-portlet` to achieve your requirement.

Comment: I think you would only require to inject your HTML and CSS in `notifications-portlet\notifications\view_entries.jsp`

Comment: In liferay-hook.xml I tried to find **notifications-portlet\notifications\view_entries.jsp** to customize it but i can't find it, can you please tell me where to find it.

Comment: `notification-portlet` is separate plugin, that can not be hooked. You will require its source to add your custom changes.

Comment: [***6.2 Portlets***](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.2.x/portlets), here you can find notification portlet's source.

Comment: Ok thanks, let me try it...